# Safecracker frontend uploaded images not uploading to specified directory and not showing in backend entries

Tags: safecracker-file

I have created a channel called user_entries, and some channel fields for name, description and file! These fields are created to be populated by a safecracker frontend form. This would allow users to submit 8 entries to the site with status pending(already created). Also to allow free uploads for users in the frontend, I have created a user called anonymous and assigned it to the Guest group. I have allowed this group to post to the channel user_entries from frontend using said safecracker form. The status needs to be pending so that the admin can change status to Open in backend, so as to filter out any entries that do not comply with the spirit of the website!

Now, everything works perfectly apart from the files. The images are being uploaded to the directory that I have created inside {site_url}/images/uploads/entries. The folder is created and the correct path specified in the CP. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Here is the code for the safecracker form:

```
   <!--============SAFECRACKER STUFF GOES RIGHT HERE=============-->
{exp:safecracker channel="user_entries" return="entries/confirmation" 
include_jquery="no" error_handling="inline"
logged_out_member_id="2"//this is the ID for user anonymous
rules:your_name="required"
rules:choice_number_1="required"
rules:choice_number_2="required"
rules:choice_number_3="required"
rules:choice_number_4="required"
rules:choice_number_5="required"
rules:choice_number_6="required"
rules:choice_number_7="required"
rules:choice_number_8="required"
rules:title="required"
dynamic="no"
}
<br class="clearfix" />
            <hr />

<h5 class="feature">Some housekeeping!</h5>
<br class="clearfix" />
            <hr />
<h2 class="feature">
    <label><strong>First please tell us your name</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="your_name" value="{your_name}"/>
    <label><strong>Give your post a memorable name</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="title" value="{title}"/>
  </h2>
 <br class="clearfix" />
            <hr />
<h2 class="feature">
    Now make your choices!
  </h2>

<fieldset class="five columns alpha aside">

  <!--Choice one code-->
  <h5>
    <label><strong>Choice number 1</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_number_1"/>
  </h5>
  <p>
    <label>Choice 1 description</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_1_description"/>
  </p>
<br />
    <label>Choice 1 image</label>
    <input type="file" class="" name="choice_1_image" value="{choice_1_image}"/> 
</fieldset>


<!--====Choice twocode-->
<fieldset class="five columns omega aside">
  <h5>
    <label><strong>Choice number 2</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_number_2"/>
  </h5>
  <p>
    <label>Choice 2 description</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_2_description"/>
  </p>
  <br />
    <label>Choice 2 image</label>
    <input type="file" class="" name="choice_2_image"/>

  </fieldset>



<!--===============Choice three code-->
<fieldset class="five columns alpha aside">

<h5>
    <label><strong>Choice number 3</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_number_3"/>
  </h5>
  <p>
    <label>Choice 3 description</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_3_description"/>
  </p>
<br />
    <label>Choice 3 image</label>
    <input type="file" class="" name="choice_3_image"/>

</fieldset>


<!--====Choice four code-->
<fieldset class="five columns omega aside">
  <h5>
    <label><strong>Choice number 4</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_number_4"/>
  </h5>
  <p>
    <label>Choice 4 description</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_4_description"/>
  </p>
<br />
    <label>Choice 4 image</label>
    <input type="file" class="" name="choice_4_image"/>  
  </fieldset>



<!--===============Choice five code-->
<fieldset class="five columns alpha aside">

<h5>
    <label><strong>Choice number 5</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_number_5"/>
  </h5>
  <p>
    <label>Choice 5 description</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_5_description"/>
  </p>
<br />
    <label>Choice 5 image</label>
    <input type="file" class="" name="choice_5_image"/>
</fieldset>


<!--====Choice six code-->
<fieldset class="five columns omega aside">
  <h5>
    <label><strong>Choice number 6</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_number_6"/>
  </h5>
  <p>
    <label>Choice 6 description</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_6_description"/>
  </p>
<br />
    <label>Choice 6 image</label>
    <input type="file" class="" name="choice_6_image"/>
  </fieldset>


<!--===============Choice seven code-->
<fieldset class="five columns alpha aside">

<h5>
    <label><strong>Choice number 7</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_number_7"/>
  </h5>
  <p>
    <label>Choice 7 description</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_7_description"/>
  </p>
<br />
    <label>Choice 7 image</label>
    <input type="file" class="" name="choice_7_image"/>
</fieldset>


<!--====Choice eight code-->
<fieldset class="five columns omega aside">
  <h5>
    <label><strong>Choice number 8</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_number_8"/>
  </h5>
  <p>
    <label>Choice 8 description</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_8_description"/>
  </p>
<br />
    <label>Have an image for Choice 8 image?</label>
    <input type="file" class="" name="choice_8_image"/>
  </fieldset>  
<!==============End the fieldsets here for the 8 choices-->
<br class="clearfix" />
            <hr />
  <p>
  <input type="submit" class="button yellow" value="Submit your choices now!" />
</p>
   <br class="clear" />
   <h2 class="feature">
    Your entries will be reviewed by either Luke or Scott and will then be published. Please keep the conversation clean. Crunch away me hardies!
  </h2>
{/exp:safecracker}
```

Your help in this is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you still having this problem?

Comment: Are your folder permissions set open enough on your destination image folder and path to it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
<label>Choice 1 image</label>
<input type="file" class="" name="choice_1_image" value="{choice_1_image}"/>
```

Try:

```
<label>Choice 1 image</label>
{field:choice_1_image}
```

I think you also need to add `safecracker_head="yes"` to get the image thumbnails to work properly.

Also, is jQuery in `<head>` tags?

Comment: jQuery is inside the <head> tag, I tried this and the images are still not uploading. I also made all the other changes you suggested. Thanks for the reply.